# get Slot Machine Effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slot machine using the following jquery plugin: [jquery slot machine](https://github.com/matthewlein/jQuery-jSlots)

I started with the simple Demo und entered my own list.  The Problem I am having is that I need more than just that block which shows 1 line of the list. I need to show what is above and beneath the middle line of the lists. So I made the `jSlotsWrapper` box bigger.

Now I have the problem that when the lists spin, at the end of the list you see empty space. How can I make that the list has no end? So where the last item in the list is, I want to start again with the list.

**EDIT**

here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Datengut Spielautomat</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    height: 62px;
}

.jSlots-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1242px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #ffa500;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
    box-shadow: inset 0 200px 100px -100px #555555, inset 0 -200px 100px -100px #555555;
}

.jSlots-wrapper::after {
    content: "";
    background:url("blumen.jpg");
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}

.slot {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 410px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px auto;
    margin-right: 5px auto;
    float: left;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-color: #ffa500;
}

.line {
    width: 410px;
    height: 2px;
    -webkit-transform:
        translateY(-20px)
        translateX(5px)

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul class="slot">
    <li>Bauakte</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Bautagebuch</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Mängelverwaltung</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Störungsverwaltung</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Personalakte</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Maschinenakte</li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<script src="jquery.1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.jSlots.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // normal example
    $('.slot').jSlots({
        number : 3,
        spinner : 'body',
        spinEvent : 'keypress',
        easing: 'easeOutSine',
        time : 7000,
        loops : 6,
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js file:

```
(function($){

$.jSlots = function(el, options){

    var base = this;

    base.$el = $(el);
    base.el = el;

    base.$el.data("jSlots", base);

    base.init = function() {

        base.options = $.extend({},$.jSlots.defaultOptions, options);

        base.setup();
        base.bindEvents();

    };


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // DEFAULT OPTIONS
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    $.jSlots.defaultOptions = {
        number : 3,          // Number: number of slots
        winnerNumber : 1,    // Number or Array: list item number(s) upon which to trigger a win, 1-based index, NOT ZERO-BASED
        spinner : '',        // CSS Selector: element to bind the start event to
        spinEvent : 'click', // String: event to start slots on this event
        onStart : $.noop,    // Function: runs on spin start,
        onEnd : $.noop,      // Function: run on spin end. It is passed (finalNumbers:Array). finalNumbers gives the index of the li each slot stopped on in order.
        onWin : $.noop,      // Function: run on winning number. It is passed (winCount:Number, winners:Array)
        easing : 'swing',    // String: easing type for final spin
        time : 7000,         // Number: total time of spin animation
        loops : 6            // Number: times it will spin during the animation
    };

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // HELPERS
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    base.randomRange = function(low, high) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * (1 + high - low) ) + low;
    };

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // VARS
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    base.isSpinning = false;
    base.spinSpeed = 0;
    base.winCount = 0;
    base.doneCount = 0;

    base.$liHeight = 0;
    base.$liWidth = 0;

    base.winners = [];
    base.allSlots = [];

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // FUNCTIONS
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------- //


    base.setup = function() {

        // set sizes

        var $list = base.$el;
        var $li = $list.find('li').first();

        base.$liHeight = $li.outerHeight();
        base.$liWidth = $li.outerWidth();

        base.liCount = base.$el.children().length;

        base.listHeight = base.$liHeight * base.liCount;

        base.increment = (base.options.time / base.options.loops) / base.options.loops;

        $list.css('position', 'relative');

        $li.clone().appendTo($list);

        base.$wrapper = $list.wrap('<div class="jSlots-wrapper"></div>').parent();

        // remove original, so it can be recreated as a Slot
        base.$el.remove();

        // clone lists
        for (var i = base.options.number - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            base.allSlots.push( new base.Slot() );
        }

    };

    base.bindEvents = function() {
        $(base.options.spinner).bind(base.options.spinEvent, function(event) {
            if (event.which == 32) {
                if (!base.isSpinning) {
                    base.playSlots();
                }
            }
        });
    };

    // Slot constructor
    base.Slot = function() {
        this.spinSpeed = 0;
        this.el = base.$el.clone().appendTo(base.$wrapper)[0];
        this.$el = $(this.el);
        this.loopCount = 0;
        this.number = 0;

    };


    base.Slot.prototype = {

        // do one rotation
        spinEm : function() {
            var that = this;

            that.$el
                .css( 'top', -base.listHeight )
                .animate( { 'top' : '0px' }, that.spinSpeed, 'linear', function() {
                    that.lowerSpeed();
                });
        },

        lowerSpeed : function() {
            this.spinSpeed += base.increment;
            this.loopCount++;

            if ( this.loopCount < base.options.loops ) {
                this.spinEm();
            } else {
                this.finish();
            }
        },

        // final rotation
        finish : function() {
            var that = this;

            var endNum = base.randomRange( 1, base.liCount );
            while (endNum % 2 == 0) {
                endNum = base.randomRange( 1, base.liCount );
            }

            var finalPos = - ( (base.$liHeight * endNum) - base.$liHeight );
            var finalSpeed = ( (this.spinSpeed * 0.5) * (base.liCount) ) / endNum;

            that.$el
                .css( 'top', -base.listHeight )
                .animate( {'top': finalPos}, finalSpeed, base.options.easing, function() {
                    base.checkWinner(endNum, that);
                });
        }
    };

    base.checkWinner = function(endNum, slot) {

        base.doneCount++;
        // set the slot number to whatever it ended on
        slot.number = endNum;

        // if its in the winners array
        if (
            ( $.isArray( base.options.winnerNumber ) && base.options.winnerNumber.indexOf(endNum) > -1 ) ||
            endNum === base.options.winnerNumber
            ) {

            // its a winner!
            base.winCount++;
            base.winners.push(slot.$el);

        }

        if (base.doneCount === base.options.number) {

            var finalNumbers = [];

            $.each(base.allSlots, function(index, val) {
                finalNumbers[index] = val.number;
            });

            if ( $.isFunction( base.options.onEnd ) ) {
                base.options.onEnd(finalNumbers);
            }

            if ( base.winCount && $.isFunction(base.options.onWin) ) {
                base.options.onWin(base.winCount, base.winners, finalNumbers);
            }
            base.isSpinning = false;
        }
    };


    base.playSlots = function() {

        base.isSpinning = true;
        base.winCount = 0;
        base.doneCount = 0;
        base.winners = [];

        if ( $.isFunction(base.options.onStart) ) {
            base.options.onStart();
        }

        $.each(base.allSlots, function(index, val) {
            this.spinSpeed = 250*index;
            this.loopCount = 0;
            this.spinEm();
        });

    };


    base.onWin = function() {
        if ( $.isFunction(base.options.onWin) ) {
            base.options.onWin();
        }
    };


    // Run initializer
    base.init();
};


// --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// JQUERY FN
// --------------------------------------------------------------------- //

$.fn.jSlots = function(options){
    if (this.length) {
        return this.each(function(){
            (new $.jSlots(this, options));
        });
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

The core functionality is the same as in the github repository.

The important part, I think, is the function `spinEm`:

```
            spinEm : function() {
            var that = this;

            that.$el
                .css( 'top', -base.listHeight )
                .animate( { 'top' : '0px' }, that.spinSpeed, 'linear', function() {
                    that.lowerSpeed();
                });
        }
```

here the list is placed above the `jSlotsWrapper` and with the animate function it moves down. Now what I need is for the animation to continue, and not to place the list at the top again. How can I achieve that.

**EDIT**

Ok, i tried the following to avoid the empty space, everytime the animation has finished:

```
        spinEm : function() {

            var that = this;

            that.$el
                .css( 'bottom', $("body").height() )
                .animate( { 'top' : '0px' }, that.spinSpeed, 'linear', function() {
                    that.lowerSpeed();
                });

        }
```

I try to place the list at the bottom of the box and move it down until the top appears. But somehow the list doesn't really move. It just moves for 1 word and then stops comletely. What is wrong in the animation code?

**EDIT**

Ok I found the solution to my problem. Apparently, I can't use `bottom` in the css function. Instead, I used `top` and calculated the position of the top border of the list. That way I have an animation without all the empty space at the beginning. To avoid the jumping from the bottom to the top of the list I modified the height of the `jSlots-Wrapper` and the order of the list items, so that the items that are displayed before and after the jump are the same. That way, the user doesn't see the list jumping.

here is my new `animate` function.

```
        spinEm : function() {
            var that = this;

            that.$el
                .css( 'top', -(base.listHeight - $("body").height()) )
                .animate( { 'top' : '0px'}, that.spinSpeed, 'linear', function() {
                    that.lowerSpeed();
                });
        }
```

Comment: code please, example, anything...?

Comment: @Pete: i added my source code. The core functionality is the same as in the Github repository.

Comment: You have empty `<li>`'s

Comment: @devqon: I know, I have these to add space between the words. The problem I have is, that when the user starts the machine the list is placed so that he only sees the word at the bottom of the list. The rest of the space is empty. And the `animate` function moves the list down. And when it is at the desired position, the list jumps to the top again and the problem is there again

Comment: You need to draw a second one when the top of the first one becomes visible?

Comment: @Mrk Fldig: yes, but how can I do that?

Comment: Hmm i'll do some reading i've only done this with HTML5 canvas, basically you need to draw a new one when the first one reaches a position, then once the first one is off the screen, remove it, rinse repeat. Give me a few hours and i'll come up with a sample!

Comment: Thank you but no need for that, i found a solution and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make the animation so that the user doesn't see the jumping. What I did, is, I configured the list in a way so that the beginning and the end are the same. So that when the end of the list is reached and it jumps to the beginning again, there is no difference. The jump is still there, but not visible for the user.